# _COORD to int or short conversion syntax?

Tags: c++, winapi

Trying to retrieve data from _COORD and store it into a variable, but I am not sure how exactly to do this. Any advice?

```
COORD WINAPI GetLargestConsoleWindowSize();
screenX = &COORD::X; screenY = &COORD::Y;
```

I get the error:
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'SHORT _COORD::* ' to 'int'

Context:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getlargestconsolewindowsize
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/coord-str

Comment: You should really get some experience with the fundamentals of the programming language before you start using APIs.  If you actually know this stuff, then maybe you just haven't slept for the last 3 days.  Most of us have been there before.

Comment: The code you shared does not produce that error message. If the answer already given does not help, edit the question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
COORD xy = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(hConsoleOutput);
short screenX = xy.X;
short screenY = xy.Y;
```

Comment: Look at the links I have, _COORD is already a given structure from WIN2000, this doesn't quite work. Thanks, though.

Comment: "*this doesn't quite work.*". What is the error message?

Comment: @cma This does work (except for the missing argument to `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize`). If it doesn't work for you, then it's likely something else in your code that's wrong (such as declaring a function instead of calling it).